# How do I add a permission for write and read access and not remove the folder?

Tags: 14.04, permissions

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed. I want to secure my folder. How can I add permissions to allow for write and read access and not removed the folder?

Comment: You might want to use Google Translate. I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write and removed permission in the linux system is same . If you set your folder permissions to writable , it can be removed . To secure your folder from everyone , I suggest you to type this command :

Example folder is /home/drajat :

> **chmod 700 -R /home/drajat**

If you want to set your folder only read for everyone type this command :

> **chmod 744 -R /home/drajat**

Info :

number 7 = its code to sent the system to make my folder is accessible(read only) , writable, and executable only for the owner(you) .

number 4 = its code to make your folder read for everyone , but they can write/removed and executable all file in your folder.

number 0 = its code to make every user and group in your system can't access , read and executable your folder .

Answer (score 0):

Why are you concerned with the removal of the folder?
Removing of a folder can only happen when it's empty. And when you give write access inside the folder, all files can be removed.
If you want a folder available at all times, you can make a script to recreate it, if it was deleted.

```
 [ ! -d *folder* ] && mkdir *folder*
```