# Obsidian cant read folder as voult: no permission to access folder

Tags: permissions, kubuntu

I tried to install and start Obsidian again (Kubunto fresh new installed)

Before my new KUbuntu installation i used the folder brain with Obsidian with no Problems. I use the same user name.

But now i got a cant access the folder error.
As you could see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMZAc.png

therefor i read here:

[How do I add a permission for write and read access and not remove the folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732257/how-do-i-add-a-permission-for-write-and-read-access-and-not-remove-the-folder/732268#732268)
and here https://askubuntu.com/a/732268/1017209

and i thought that probably helps

`sudo chmod 744 -R ./brain/`

hopefully gives my app-image (Obsidian) access to read and write to this folder.

but it do no. Any idea?

Comment: works if i use `sudo chmod 777 -R ./brain/` then i could open it with Obsidian. probably not good solution. but as workaround the first time. BTW This folder was created by Obsidian before me re-installation of Kubunto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. After trying to change the owner of the folder it occurs to me that maybe the problem is in the permissions of obsidian as other apps installed through deb packages or fltapak acces the same folder witouth any error.

So i find this answer that helped me:
[How to give a Flatpak app access to a directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086529/how-to-give-a-flatpak-app-access-to-a-directory)

I've tryed first the command line but it doesn't work so, i installed the flatseal and add the mounted driver and folder to the permissions.